# How do i save the user in django model from class based views

Tags: django

I'm moving across from function-based views to class-based views but am having some trouble saving the `user` in my database.

I managed to get it to work (after some trying!) in my function based view:

```
# def create_post(request, *args, **kwargs): #function based view for creating a post - this works
#     if request.method == "POST":
#         form = PostForm(request.POST)
#         if form.is_valid():
#             post = form.save(commit=False)
#             post.author = request.user
#             post.save()
#             messages.success(request, "Post submitted!")
#             form = PostForm()
#     else:
#         form = PostForm()
#
#     context = {
#         'form': form
#     }
#     return render(request, "create_post.html", context)
```

but can't get it to work when doing classed based views.

CreatePostView:

```
class CreatePostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "create_post.html"
```

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:post_detail", args=(str(self.id),))
```

Post Form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['title'].label = ""
        self.fields['description'].label = ""


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'description']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "title w-full bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 p-2 mb-4 outline-none",
                                            'spellcheck': "false", 'placeholder': "Title", 'type': "text"}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': "description w-full bg-gray-100 sec p-3 h-60 border border-gray-300 outline-none",
                                                 'spellcheck': "false", 'placeholder': "Describe everything about this post here", 'type': "text"}),
        }

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

I think the problem lies in the `save` method, I don't really understand what I need to do here to save my user in my model. With the function based view I just grabbed the user with `request.user` and saved it as my `post.author`.

Comment: there is no `request` in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [**`.form_valid(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) to run when the form is valid, and before the form is saved and a redirect is made:

```
class CreatePostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'create_post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin).

Comment: And I don't need to pass in the  ```request``` variable? That just comes with whatever ```form``` is?

Comment: @Callum: sorry, it is `self.request.user` :)

Comment: This still isn't saving my user.id in my author variable. There's no error, it's just remaining blank even though I have logged in. Is there anything else that I should be looking out for to see if I've not done?

Comment: @Callum: aarrgghhh, it's author, ok, `form.instance.author = ...`.

Comment: Apologies, even I could have spotted that last mistake but it works! Much appreciated